# Adding a dynamic range into my VBA to Outlook macro

Tags: excel, vba, automation, outlook

I wrote a macro that takes a specific range of my Worksheet and pastes it into an email.  The range is currently hardcoded into my macro.  I need it to change bases on if certain rows are empty or not.  I have found a way to get Excel to output the range I need in a cell with an nested if statement, but I need help getting that into my macro.

**Here's my code that writes the email**

```
Sub ChemGlassCopyRangeToOutlook_single()
    
    'Declare Outlook Vairables
    Dim oLookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oLookItm As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oLookIns As Outlook.Inspector
    
    'Declare Word Vaiables
    Dim oWrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oWrdRng As Word.Range
    
    'Declare Excel Variables
    Dim ExcRng As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    'Get the Active instance of Outlook
    Set oLookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    
        'If error create a new instance of outlook
        If Err.Number = 429 Then
            'Clear Error
            Err.Clear
            
            'Create new instance of Outlook
            Set oLookApp = New Outlook.Application
            
        End If
    'Create a new email 'Possible Problem here
    Set oLookItm = oLookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    'Create a reference to the ex range you want to export
    Set ExcRng = Sheet1.Range("B15:G20")
    
    With oLookItm
    
        'Define basic info
        'Range("m3").Copymight not need
        .From = "ABC@XYZ.com"
        
        .To = "123@XYZ.com"
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = Range("m3")
        
        .Body = "Please review the attached invoices and confirm that the goods or services have been received and payment should be made."

        'Display email
        .Display
        'Left off at time stamp 12:39
        'Get the active inspector
        Set oLookIns = .GetInspector
        
        'Get word editor
        Set oWrdDoc = oLookIns.WordEditor
        
        'Specify rang in document
        Set oWrdRng = oWrdDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
            oWrdRng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        
        'Add new paragraphand then insert break
        Set oWrdRng = oWdEditor.Paragraph.Add
            oWrdRng.InsertBreak
        
        'Copy the Range
        ExcRng.Copy
        
        'Paste it
        oWrdRng.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
        
    End With
EndSub
```

**Here's what I wrote in Excel to get the range I need**

```
'=IF(B20<>"","B15:G20",(IF(B19<>"","B15:g19",(IF(B18<>"","B15:G18",(IF(B17<>"","B15:G17",FALSE)))))))
```

Is there a way to get VBA to pull the output of the cell with this formula?

Also this feels very rube golberg-y, if anyone has a better idea I'm open, but at the same time except for this not being dynamic, it works :-D

TIA

Comment: You can write a function that returns the Excel range (or the address of the range).  Turn that nested `if` statement into a `Select Case` statement in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Range.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value) property which returns a value that represents the value of the specified range. The [Range.Formula](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula) property returns a value that represents the object's implicitly intersecting formula in A1-style notation. If the cell contains a formula, the `Formula` property returns the formula as a string in the same format that would be displayed in the formula bar (including the equal sign ( = )).